# Problem with api request using RestSharp in .Net Maui

Tags: c#, maui, restsharp, maui-blazor

I'm newbie to .Net Maui and RestSharp, I'm mostly Unity developer. I have this request

```
using RestSharp;

namespace FindPlacesApp.Code.ApiRequests
{
    public class SearchPlacesRequest
    {
        public async Task<string> GetPlaces(double latitude, double longitude, int radius)
        {
            try
            {
                var options = new RestClientOptions("https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/search");

                var client = new RestClient(options);

                var request = new RestRequest();

                request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                request.AddHeader("Authorization", Constants.apiKey);

                request.AddQueryParameter("ll", $"{latitude},{longitude}");

                request.AddQueryParameter("radius", radius.ToString());

                var response = await client.GetAsync(request);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) await AlertDisplayer.DisplayError($"Unsuccess: {response.StatusCode}");

                return response.Content;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await AlertDisplayer.DisplayError($"Exception: {ex}");
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

It perfecly works when on Windows build, but on Android build i get exception "Bad Request" on the line `var response = await client.GetAsync(request);` The problem not in latitude, longitude, radius or Internet status, I checked that. Is theare problems with RestSharp on Android using .Net Maui or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: complete guess, but I would try calling with all parameters as integer instead of decimals

Comment: "Bad Request" means the server did not like your request.  You need to read the API docs to determine why you're getting this response.  There are also numerous existing questions about errors from the FourSquare API

Comment: It perfecly works on Windows build, but not on Android so I suppose theare no errors with my request

Comment: well obviously the server thinks there is.  You can't fix the problem if you can't identify the root cause

Comment: That's the reason why I post this question, because I don't know what is exactly causing "bad request"

Comment: Again, read the API docs and look at the many existing questions on this topic.

Comment: I decided to try httpclient instead of restsharp and now I have problem with api key, my api key ends with '=' symbol and as I tested I have error with this code: Headers =
{
    { "accept", "application/json" },
    { "Authorization", Constants.apiKey }
} The format of value (Constants.apiKey value) is invalid, how to fix this? Because I can't just change value of my api key and remove '=' from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix my problem. I moved from RestSharp to httpclient but that dont help me too much. then after some tests I find out that latitude and longitude formating on Android was wrong and not the same as on my Pc. I fix that by this way:

```
string formattedLatitude = latitude.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedLongitude = longitude.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here is my end and working varinat

```
namespace FindPlacesApp.Code.ApiRequests
{
    public class SearchPlacesRequest
    {
        public async Task<string> GetPlaces(double latitude, double longitude, int radius)
        {
            try
            {
                string formattedLatitude = latitude.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string formattedLongitude = longitude.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var client = new HttpClient();
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = new Uri($"https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/search?ll={formattedLatitude}%2C{formattedLongitude}&radius={radius}"),
                    Headers =
                    {
                        { "accept", "application/json" },
                    }
                };

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", Constants.apiKey);

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request); 

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return contentString;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await AlertDisplayer.DisplayError($"Exception: {ex}");
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark it as accepted.